# ERROR: "SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference."

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have got a problem with my code in Fortran 95. I try to write a code, that calculates something and prints into a .txt, so that I can plot with some plotting program. It is just for me, for trying.
The error is:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

```
      FUNCTION RAD(GRAD) RESULT(RADIANS)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: GRAD
      REAL :: RADIANS

      REAL, PARAMETER :: RAD2DE = 3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0

      RADIANS = GRAD * RAD2DE
      END FUNCTION RAD

      PROGRAM MAIN
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER   :: STA, STO, SIZE,  I, UNIT
      REAL :: SCHR, X0, Y0 , R, THETA, INC, A, B, TERM2, ZMP, ZY01, ZY02, RAD
      REAL, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: X, Y, Z, ZE1, ZE2, ZM, Z1, Z2

      CHARACTER(LEN=20) :: filename1 = "cone_y.txt"
      CHARACTER(LEN=20) :: filename2 = "cone_x.txt"

      THETA = RAD(60)
      INC = RAD(50)
      SCHR = 0.001
      R = 1.0
      STA = -1
      STO = 1

      ! STA shoud be negative
      SIZE =  INT(R * (STO- STA) / SCHR + 1)
      ! erstelle Arr in der richtigen grö?ß?e
      ALLOCATE(X(1:SIZE))
      ALLOCATE(Y(1:SIZE))
      ALLOCATE(Z(1:SIZE))
      ALLOCATE(ZE1(1:SIZE))
      ALLOCATE(ZE2(1:SIZE))
      ALLOCATE(Z1(1:SIZE))
      ALLOCATE(Z2(1:SIZE))

      ! plotting range
      DO I = 1, SIZE
        X(I) = STA + REAL(I) * SCHR
        Y(I) = STA + REAL(I) * SCHR
        Z(I) = STA + I * SCHR
      END DO
      !Cal ZE1

      DO I = 1, SIZE
        ZE1(I) = Y(I) / ( TAN( INC - THETA ) )
        ZE2(I) = Y(I) / ( TAN( INC + THETA ) )
      END DO

      DO I = 1, SIZE
        ZM(I) = 0.5 * ( ZE1(I) + ZE2(I) )
      END DO

      Y0 = 0.1
      !output in .txt
      OPEN(UNIT = 1 , file = filename1, status = "replace")

      DO I = 1, SIZE
        WRITE(UNIT, *) Z(I), ", ", ZE1(I)
      END DO

      CLOSE(UNIT)
      !Nun begint die berechnung der Hyperbel 
      ZY01 = Y0 / TAN( INC - THETA )
      ZY02 = Y0 / TAN( INC + THETA )

      ZMP = 0.5 * ( ZY01 + ZY02 )

      B = ( Y0 ** 2.0 + ZMP ** 2.0 ) * TAN( THETA )
      A = 0.5 * ( ZY01 - ZY02)

      DO I = 1, SIZE
        TERM2 = SQRT(((X(I) ** 2 ) / (B**2) -1.0) * A**2 )
        Z1(I) = ZMP + TERM2
        Z2(I) = ZMP - TERM2
      END DO

      OPEN(UNIT = 2 , file = filename2, status = "replace")

      DO I = 1, SIZE
        WRITE(UNIT, *) Z1(I), ",", Z2(I), ",", Z(I)
      END DO

      CLOSE(UNIT)
       
      
      PRINT *, "Arr wrote into ", trim(filename1)

      END PROGRAM MAIN
```

For compiling I use the gfortran compiler and I execute it with `./FILE.out`.

I have no experience with this kind of coding, cause I am coming from Python and this is one of my first codes and I can not find the problem.
I'm use my Mac with ARM CPU.

I searched about the error and I found out, that it could be a problem with the arrays, but I don't know.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Use tag [tag:fortran] and read the descriptions of the tags you are adding.

Comment: When getting errors like this you should compile using debugging flags of the compiler. E.g., `gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all`.

Comment: You failed to allocate ZM before using it. Actually, you failed to allocate it anywhere.